# How to query one-to-many relation with condition on main model

Tags: laravel, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I know it is possible and maybe I had already done it, I need to refresh my memory. Let say we have one-to-many

```
$post->comments
```

and I want
Comments on this post where comment date is greater than specific date. I don't want to get this specific date in php value. Because I want to use it as generic column name.

```
$myComments = $post->comments->where('published', '>=', 'posts.updated_at');
```

I do someething like but I am getting

> Column not found

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 3 problems here:

First, `$post->comments` is a `Collection`, and does not use SQL *at all*, so `posts.updated_at` will not be available, but `$post->updated_at` would be.

Second, Relationships don't use `joins`, so `posts.updated_at` is not going to be available unless you manually join it.

Third, `->where()` is a `string` match, so your query is literally `WHERE published = 'projects.updated_at'`, which will return `0` results. You'd need to use `->whereColumn()` there.

You can solve this by "Eager Loading" Comments with that `where()` clause:

```php
$post = Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
  return $query->select('comments.*')
  ->join('posts', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
  ->whereColumn('comments.published', '>=', 'posts.updated_at');
})->first();

// Or `$posts = Post::with([ /* ... */ ])->get();
```

Or keep the `->comments` syntax, but pass the attribute, not the SQL field:

```php
$myComments = $post->comments->where('published', '>=', $post->updated_at)
```

Or, finally, use `->comments()` with the same syntax as Eager Loading:

```php
$myComments = $post->comments()
->select('comments.*')
->join('posts', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
->whereColumn('comments.published', '>=', 'posts.updated_at')
->get();
```

Comment: I used to make another join, and i was finding a way to avoid without using php variable... Thanks for quick reply, your first proposition is suited for what i want ( using ->get()). your entire response is clear and a lot usefull for many situations!

Comment: Excellent! And yes, I would recommend using Eager Loading where possible! You could even extract this to a relationship, like `public function publishedComments() { return $this->select(...)->join(...)->whereColumn(...); }`, then simply `$posts = Post::with(['publishedComments'])->get();`, but depends if you need to reuse this, etc. Cheers!